# How to copy the data by using Amazon Aurora from One Region to another region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

How to copy the data by using Amazon Aurora from One Region to another region. I learned that through MYSQL we can achieve this. Do you have any steps for that?

Can someone please help me to understand How Amazon Aurora is compatible with MYSQL?

Answer (score 0):

Aurora allows you to back up your data by taking snapshots of your database clusters [1]. You can then copy your snapshots to another region [2].

The Aurora MySQL engine is forked from open source MySQL, and the Aurora team has made changes on top of it. That is why Aurora is compatible with MySQL.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_CreateSnapshotCluster.html
[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-copy-snapshot.html

Answer (score 0):

You can copy a snapshot to another AWS Region as already mentioned, and restore it there. That's a one-time operation that gives you another copy of the data from a point in time.

You can also copy the data continuously using Aurora global database:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-global-database.html

With a global database, the changes get propagated from the primary cluster to 1-5 secondary clusters in other AWS Regions. (The secondary clusters are read-only except for the data being transmitted from the original Region.) This mechanism is faster and lower-overhead than doing cross-Region replication using MySQL binlog replication. You can keep the data synchronized across all the Regions, or detach one of the secondary clusters so that it gains full read-write capability.